# Allow/Deny User no funciona correctamente

Tags: asp.net

No puedo hacer andar la seguridad en un sitio web. En el web config Raiz pongo la siguiente línea:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Luego, en la carpeta "Account" tengo el siguiente `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Account/Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
       <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Asi como esta puesto, NO puedo entrar a la pagina `Register.aspx`, me tira un error de Persmisos.

```
*Acceso denegado.
Descripción: Error al obtener acceso a los recursos necesarios para completar esta solicitud. Puede que el servidor no esté configurado para obtener acceso a la dirección URL solicitada. 
Mensaje de error 401.2.: No autorizado: error al iniciar sesión debido a la configuración de servidor. Compruebe que tiene permiso para ver este directorio o página con las credenciales que ha suministrado y los métodos de autenticación habilitados en el servidor Web. Póngase en contacto con el administrador del servidor Web para obtener más ayuda.*
```

Si elimino del `web.config` principal la linea **`deny users="?"`** entra a todas las paginas correctamente, es decir, la pagina esta andando, solo la bloquea esta "seguridad".

Si quito el `web.config` de la carpeta "Account" cuando quiero entrar me redirige a la pagina de login, tal como lo establece la autenticacion en el webconfig Raíz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta usar esto para acceder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="Register.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="~/Account/Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
          <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>
     </system.web>
  </location>
    <system.web>
       <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrador"/>
            <deny users="*"/>
       </authorization>
    </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Con esta última línea bloqueas a todos las páginas y subdirectorios a menos que cumplan los roles de  Administrador.

Mas ejemplos [en esta liga](http://www.elguille.info/NET/ASPNET/indicar_elementos_publicos_privados.htm).

Indicaciones técnicas de Microsoft fáciles de entender [en esta liga](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/wce3kxhd(v=vs.100).aspx).